# linear mapping is an open mapping in vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(N,\|\; \|)$ and $(N_1, \|\;\|_1)$ be normed vector spaces and $f$ a linear mapping of $N$ into $N_1$. Prove that $f$ is an open mapping if and only if for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)) \supseteq B_r (0)$, for some $r>0$

I could prove $\Rightarrow$, but could not prove the other way. I assume I have to show that $f(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0))$ is open in $N_1$. $f(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0)) \supseteq B_r (0)$ is just showing there is some open balls inside $f(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0))$. I think this does not necessarily mean that $f(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(0))$ is open.. How am I supposed to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $N$ and $x\in U.$ Then there exists $\epsilon>0$  s. th. $U\supseteq B_{\epsilon}(x)$.
Now use $f(U)\supseteq f(B_{\epsilon}(x))=f(x)+\epsilon f(B_{1}(0)) $ and your assumption to conclude
that there is an open ball arround $f(x)$ that lies entirely in $f(U)$.

Comment: If $f(B_{1/n}(0)) \nsupseteq B_r(0)$, at which point does this proof fail to hold?

Comment: Does it like, $f(U) \supset f(B_\varepsilon (x)) = f(x) + \epsilon f(B_1(0)) \supset f(x) + \varepsilon B_r(0) = f(x) + \varepsilon(B_r(f(0))) = \varepsilon B_r(f(x))$? Since this holds for all x, $f(U)$ must be open

Comment: yes but the penualtimate equality is not useful for the argument and can be deleted